# What does "macht" mean in "Was macht Tina?”

Tags: word-usage, question, interrogative

I have just started learning the basic German language. In an exercise, I had to fill in the blank in the following question with a question word:

> W___ macht Tina?

I saw that *macht* means *power/make* and it does not make any sense to write a question which ends with *make/power Tina*?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense a sentence ending in *make Tina*?

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. It is clearly not a translation request, but an honest effort to understand what the sentence can mean and why it can mean that, starting from a hypothesis (that "macht" is a noun) that is reasonable for a beginner. I can see other people making the same mistake, in which case tihs question will be of use to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing a noun with a verb.

The verb *machen* means ‘to make’, ‘to do’, while the noun *die Macht* means ‘power’.

> ich mache
>
> du machst
>
> er/sie/es macht
>
> wir machen
>
> ihr macht
>
> sie/Sie machen

In your example, Tina is referring to *she (sie)* and because of this reason, the question is in the sense of “What does Tina do/make?”. In the question, you wrote in your question, the conjugated verb *macht* ‘[she] does’ is used instead of the noun *Macht* ‘power’.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to add, that it cannot be a noun, as it is not capitalised.

Answer (score 7):

*machen* also means "do". There's only one possibility of meaning since there's no objective:

> **Was** macht Tina? - What is Tina *doing*?

Comment: **Wie** macht Tina? - "oink"

Comment: **Wann** macht Tina? Morgens, gleich nach dem Aufstehen...

Comment: **Wer** macht Tina? Die Redaktion und einige freie Mitarbeiter. http://www.illuservice.de/zeitschriften/?id_item=26&illustrierte=tina

Comment: Wohin macht Tina? Ins Katzenklo.

Comment: **Wieviel** macht Tina? Die macht so Dreitausend im Monat.

Comment: **Wieso/weshalb/warum** macht Tina? Weil sie muss. @tofro Jetzt neu: die *Wehrmacht-Tina* – Militaria für Mädchen!

Comment: Welchen macht Tina? Den anderen. Wozu Macht, Tina? Wessen Macht, Tina?

Comment: **Wen** macht Tina? Einen Androiden.

Comment: **Wunder** macht Tina? Ja, denn sie ist eine Heilige.

Comment: **Welchen** macht Tina? – Den da.

Comment: **Warum** macht Tina? - Weil sie mal muss.

Answer (score 1):

***Was macht*** also has a colloquial meaning that could be rephrased as "What's new to tell about...?" This is a very handy phrase for German learners that can be applied to anything:

> Und was macht Tina so? - *Die hat ihr Studium geschmissen und gibt
> jetzt Surfkurse auf Fuerteventura.*
>
> Was macht deine Wohnungssuche? - *Schwierig. Immer passt irgendwas
> nicht, meistens die Höhe der Miete.*
>
> Was macht dein Deutsch? - *Jaa, langsam langsam ist es ein bisschen
> besser.*

The typical situation for this would be not having seen someone for a certain period of time and then briefly 'going over' the common themes.